# NullPointerException while inserting into oracle database

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have JDBC Class and Servlet class separately in 2 packages.
I try to fetch data from an HTML form and insert it into a table.
This is the Servlet class code to fetch data

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
                    throws ServletException, IOException {

    String userName = request.getParameter("UserName");
    String password = request.getParameter("Password");
    String country = request.getParameter("Country");
    String address = request.getParameter("Address");
    String gender = request.getParameter("Gender");
    String years = request.getParameter("Years");
    String bDate = request.getParameter("BirthDate");
    Boolean hasCar = null; 
    if (request.getParameter("Car")!= null){
        hasCar = true;
    }else{
        hasCar = false;
        }
```

and this is the method in JDBC class to insert data

```
public static void insertData(User user){


        String sql = "insert into users values (1,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        String userName = user.getUserName();
        String password = user.getPassword();
        String address = user.getAddress();
        String country = user.getCountry();
        String gender = user.getGender();
        int years = Integer.parseInt(user.getYears());
        String bbd = user.getBDate();
        Date bDate = null;
    try {
        bDate = (Date) new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(bbd);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    boolean hasCar = user.isHasCar();
        try {
            ps.setString(1, userName);
            ps.setString(2, password);
            ps.setString(3, country);
            ps.setString(4, address);
            ps.setString(5, gender);
            ps.setInt(6, years);
            ps.setDate(7, bDate);
            ps.setBoolean(8, hasCar);


            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.executeUpdate(sql);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I created an object from class user in Servlet class and passed it to JDBC method and redirect into another html page

```
    User user = new User(userName, password, country, address, gender, years, bDate, hasCar);
    JDBCClass.insertData(user);
response.sendRedirect("Home.html");
```

but it throws java.lang.nullpointerexception

What is wrong?

[Error photo](https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=501077513487)

Comment: in which line you get this exception?

Comment: ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql); after try

Answer (score 0):

In your code you define `PreparedStatement ps = null;` and invoke `ps.setString()`first and then initial it,that's the reason cause NullPointerException,you need to init it before using it

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);//need to init it now
ps.setString(1, userName);
ps.setString(2, password);
ps.setString(3, country);
ps.setString(4, address);
ps.setString(5, gender);
ps.setInt(6, years);
ps.setDate(7, bDate);
ps.setBoolean(8, hasCar);


//ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);//this is the wrong place
ps.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Also,it's a very bad practice to omit column name when insert data

```
 String sql = "insert into users values (1,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; //it's bad,since you omit the column name
 String sql = "insert into users (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9)
   values (1,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but still not working. I added a photo of the error in the question. This appears when i click save button.

Comment: @A.Maher your photo need account to visit for it,thus we can not see it

Answer (score 0):

**To answer your question :**

You declare `PreparedStatement ps = null;` and then you try to execute method `ps.setString(int,String)` while `ps` is still `null`.

Prepared statements should be "prepared" before you assign the form values to their proper position indexes.

If you move the `ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);` before the value assignation it should work. Like so:

```
boolean hasCar = user.isHasCar();
    try {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, userName);
        ps.setString(2, password);
        ps.setString(3, country);
        ps.setString(4, address);
        ps.setString(5, gender);
        ps.setInt(6, years);
        ps.setDate(7, bDate);
        ps.setBoolean(8, hasCar);

        ps.executeUpdate(sql);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Comment:**

I would like to note that assigning variables to null makes your code more prone to those types of errors that we observe here.